# Array randomly shuffles while having ~ 500 rows in twig

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, symfony, twig

I am creating one big array in controller, based on the database. Then in twig I display it. The problem is that sometimes, randomly, this array seems to be shuffled. After I refresh the page it's normal, but then again it's shuffled, there's no pattern for when it is normal.

PHP array in the controller looks good, there's no problem with it. Then I pass it to the template:

```
return $this->render('AcmeBundle:FooController:bar.html.twig', [
  'allResults' => $results
]);
```

And then display it inside twig template:

```
{% for r in allResults %}
  {{ r.id }} {{ r.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

What happens now is that it sometimes causes the page to look like this:

[image]

I created dump inside twig template to see what the array itself looks like, and I got:

```
array (size=437)   'karmv>
   psa' =>      array (size=4)   ;">
'id' => string 'karmv>
   psa' (length=13)   ;">
'pid' => string 'lias="drapa v>zwierzat' (length=22)   ;">
'pr" uct_count' => string '1' (length=1)   ;">
'popularity' => string '766' (length=3)   'wor  dgimna =>      array (size=4)   ;">
'id' => string 'wor  dgimna  (length=18)   ;">
'pid' => string 'y-ertcol-md-3" s' (length=16)   ;">
'pr" uct_count' => string '1' (length=1)   ;">
'popularity' => string '741' (length=3)   'gadz   
elektroniczne' =>      array (size=4)   ;">
'id' => string 'gadz   
elektroniczne' (length=21)   ;">
'pid' => string 'gadz
```

While when it's ok it looks like this:

```
array (size=437)
  'karma-dla-psa' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string 'karma-dla-psa' (length=13)
      'pid' => string 'akcesoria-dla-zwierzat' (length=22)
      'product_count' => string '41' (length=1)
      'popularity' => string '412' (length=3)
  'worki-gimnastyczne' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string 'worki-gimnastyczne' (length=18)
      'pid' => string 'sport-dla-dzieci' (length=16)
      'product_count' => string '151' (length=1)
      'popularity' => string '74' (length=3)
  'gadzety-elektroniczne' => 
    array (size=4)
      'id' => string 'gadzety-elektroniczne' (length=21)
      'pid' => string 'gadzety-komputerowe' (length=19)
      'product_count' => string '71' (length=2)
      'popularity' => string '441' (length=3)
```

What's going on? Why does that happen?

Comment: Could you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I don't know how could I provide a better example in this case :(

Comment: Please start fresh and create the minimal code to reproduce the issue, so that we can test and debug on our own machines.

Comment: So there are 2 issues: array is shuffled randomly and your dump output looks like garbage. And by seeing your screenshot, at the bottom, it looks like there are other garbage. I'm sorry but as this currently stands, we'll not be able to help. You should give us more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never use twig yet or read about it, but from my experience if your extracting data from DB, you should have it sorted `order by` as there is no certainty on how the data is sorted before processing it.

Once you have the data in the array, you can then randomized it as needed.

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question and the DB doesn't have anything to do about it, the problem isn't that the rows aren't ordered, this looks almost like memory corruption, the array is totally messed up.

Comment: @AndreDaniel How do you know for sure that the rows are ordered when they leave the database after the query? Did you debug that? Have you tried explicit `order by`? Don't resort to believing in unlikely scenarios (mem corr.) when unexpected things happen during development.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek From the example he provided it doesn't look like an ordering issue, here some characters from the fields are randomly missing, `karma-dla-psa` becomes `'karmv> psa` and it looks more like a bug in some low-level framework function that handles arrays (most likely) or memory corruption (least likely but possible nonetheless).

Comment: If I remember correctly, the problem was that the data was just too big to pass it through the controller into the twig template file. Because sf2 treats it like objects, or something like that...